# Change parents theme functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

All I need to change is `__( 'Expiry (MM/YY)', 'woocommerce' )` to `Expiration Date` .
I have tried creating a file just like it to see if it overriders the parents theme `/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-payment-gateway.php` but that didn't work.

```
public function credit_card_form( $args = array(), $fields = array() ) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );

        ...

    <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry">' . __( 'Expiry (MM/YY)', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label>

        ...
    );
}
```

**How do I change plugins functionality (just msg) with out hard coding the plugin itself**

Comment: you cant declare the same function twice, so what you can do is unhook the original function and then hook your own in. Some themes do look in the stylesheet directory rather than template directory but that depends on the dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gettext filter to translate string with text domain.

```
function __text_string_translate( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Expiry (MM/YY)' :
        $translated_text = __( 'Expiration Date', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', '__text_string_translate', 20, 3 );
```